# Javascript: Expecting an Identifier and instead saw 'else'. Missing ";" before statement

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement

I'm teaching myself javascript via code Academy and keep getting "unexpected token else".  What am I missing:

```
function creditCheck(income) {
    var ans = 100; if(income>=100);     
    return("You earn a lot of money! You qualify for a credit card."); 
} 
else {     
    return("Alas you do not qualify for a credit card. Capitalism is cruel like that." ); 
}
```

creditCheck(75);
creditCheck(125);
creditCheck(100);

Comment: `var ans = 100; if(income>=100);` remove `;` from end of this line and add `{`

Comment: You'll need a corresponding } after the return statement, too.

Answer (score 1):

JSLint would complain about the examples given. It prefers:

```
function creditCheck(income) {
   var ans = 100; 
   if (income >= 100) {
       return("You earn a lot of money! You qualify for a credit card."); 
   } 
   return("Alas you do not qualify for a credit card. Capitalism is cruel like that."); 
}
```

I mention this because the else in the code examples is unecessary if it only contains a final return.

Answer (score 0):

Your code now does `function creditcheck() { ...} else {...}`
A function doesnt have an `else{}`. You made a small mistake with the if, this is the correct way:

```
function creditCheck(income) {
    var ans = 100;
    if(income>=100){
        return("You earn a lot of money! You qualify for a credit card."); 
    } 
    else {     
        return("Alas you do not qualify for a credit card. Capitalism is cruel like that." ); 
    } 
}
```

Or the method I would use:

```
function creditCheck(income) {
    var ans = 100;
    var returnValue;
    if(income>=100){ returnValue = "You earn a lot of money! You qualify for a credit card."; } 
    else {           returnValue = "Alas you do not qualify for a credit card. Capitalism is cruel like that."; } 

    return returnValue; // Return it at the end. This way the action `return` only happends at the end
}
```

This is allot easier for debugging. If you want to check which value gets returned, you just add `console.log(returnValue);` a line above the return.

Answer (score 0):

remove one ; and add {

```
function creditCheck(income) 
{
       var ans = 100; 
       if(income>=100)
       {
           return("You earn a lot of money! You qualify for a credit card."); 
       } 
       else
       {     
           return("Alas you do not qualify for a credit card. Capitalism is cruel like that."   ); 
       }
}
```

if you don't wanna put { you can write..

```
function creditCheck(income) 
{
       var ans = 100; 
       if(income>=100)
           return("You earn a lot of money! You qualify for a credit card."); 
       else
           return("Alas you do not qualify for a credit card. Capitalism is cruel like that."   ); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is how you solve your code:

```
function creditCheck(income) {
    var ans = 100; 
    if(income>=100){     
        return("You earn a lot of money! You qualify for a credit card."); 
    }else {     
        return("Alas you do not qualify for a credit card. Capitalism is cruel like that." ); 
    }
}
```

The else should be right after if statement

Answer (score 0):

It's important to make sure that each opening bracket has a matching closing bracket.

Your code:

```
function creditCheck(income) {
    var ans = 100;
    if(income>=100);
    return("You earn a lot of money! You qualify for a credit card."); 
    } 
    else {     
        return("Alas you do not qualify for a credit card. Capitalism is cruel like that." ); 
}
```

should be formatted like:

```
function creditCheck(income)
{
    var ans = 100;
    // I'm assuming that you mean to compare 'income' with 'ans'
    // Notice that I replaced ';' with an opening bracket here
    if(income>=ans) 
    {  
        return("You earn a lot of money! You qualify for a credit card."); 
    }
    else
    {     
        return("Alas you do not qualify for a credit card. Capitalism is cruel like that." );
    }
    // And here I've added a closing bracket
}
```

When you only have a single operation within a conditional block (such as `if`) formed by brackets you don't actually need the opening and closing brackets. See below.

```
// 
function creditCheck(income)
{
    var ans = 100;
    // See, no more brackets here
    if(income>=ans) 
        return("You earn a lot of money! You qualify for a credit card."); 
    else
        return("Alas you do not qualify for a credit card. Capitalism is cruel like that." );
}
```